# User Logon Script - Display additional network information

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy, windows-server, event-viewer

I have a GPO which runs a PowerShell script on user logon for a particular user.

GPO Location:

[image]

This script sends an email whenever the user logs onto the domain, this email contains the computer name of which this account was logged onto along with a date/time stamp.

```
$MailMessage.Body = "User: Tom Logged into " + $env:computername + " Date: " + (Get-Date).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
```

What I'm looking to add onto this email is remote computer location of which this account was logged in from, for example:

Email:

> User: Tom Logged into workstation-1 Date: 01/01/2021 08:30:00am **from remote-workstation-5**

Is there an environment string that somehow shows this?

Using event logs may be the correct procedure but I have not found any events that show this information for all computers on the network. Event ID 4624 does not even show the workstation name, only the IP with a large collection of obsolete logs. Event 4778 displays the user was accessed and the original remote computer, but only events related to the local server not the domain.

Comment: Not foolproof but if it's an RDP connection, you could use `get-nettcpconnection | sort creationtime -desc | select -first 1`.  If it's any other way of connecting, you could play with the parameters a bit or just return the lastest x connections in your mail and try to figure it out from there.

Comment: (I meant `get-nettcpconnection -port 3389`)

Comment: Thanks @LievenKeersmaekers. Output of this has given me "MSFT_NetTCPConnection (InstanceID = "10.XX.XX.XX??60504??20.XX.XX.XXX??443")"

XX is where I've changed numbers. Gives IP of the server which was logged onto and another IP unrelated to anything. But not anything linked to the remote computer I used to log into said server. Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: Using `get-nettcpconnection | sort creationtime -desc` I would definitely expect your IP to be visible in the output. Depending on server load, it might not be the most recent one though so that's the *not foolproof* part of it.

Comment: That's a good idea Lieven K., check this output out that tells me the IP of the connected machines via RDP standard port `Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3389 | Select CreationTime, RemoteAddress`. You might need to resolve the IP to a DNS name  if it's applicable in your environment but that's only a trivial matter too.

Comment: Thanks @PillsburyITDoughboy and LievanKeersmaekers. Pillsbury your output from Lieven's code is exactly what I need when punching it into a PowerShell prompt. When pasting it into my script, it does not output the result. I can get the first line if I put -first 1 on the end, how can I output all the lines?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers -first1 only displays @{CreationTime=05/11/2021 20:55:35; RemoteAddress=::}. Pasting with a PowerShell prompt displays all the IP results underneath. Removing -first1 from the script outputs nothing, using -first2 outputs nothing which should show the first IP result. Any ideas?

Comment: @S_T perhaps `(Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3389 | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select CreationTime, RemoteAddress -First 1).RemoteAddress` or just `Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3389 | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select CreationTime, RemoteAddress -First 1` or some sort of variation like that?

Comment: @PillsburyITDoughboy That's done it! Last thing, Get-NetTCPConnection does not work with Windows 2008 R2. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: @S_T Something like this `@([System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpConnections())` but you will need to parse the endpoint by splitting on the semicolon, etc. to get the port I think. Just a trivial matter of figuring out the correct logic to get you the needed result. Sample for quick thoughts .... `@([System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpConnections()) | % { $_.LocalEndPoint -Split(":") }`

Comment: Thanks @PillsburyITDoughboy that did it. Feel free to post an answer and I'll mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to us PSTermialServices: (https://github.com/imseandavis/PSTerminalServices)

Run command:   `Get-TSSession -ComputerName PC01` or `Get-TSSession -ComputerName localhost`

You will get the following values:

[image]

This can tell you both ways, what computer a user is remoted into and where, as well as, who is remoted into the local machine and from where.

Answer (score 0):

As per the commented suggestion, you can use the [Get-NetTCPConnection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=windowsserver2019-ps) cmdlet to view TCP connection properties such as local or remote IP address, local or remote port, and connection state.

### PowerShell Examples

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3389 | Select CreationTime, RemoteAddress
```

**Output**

> ```
> CreationTime          RemoteAddress
> ------------          -------------
> 5/12/2021 10:18:58 PM ::           
> 5/24/2021 7:40:33 AM  10.99.99.11   
> 5/12/2021 10:18:58 PM 0.0.0.0
> ```

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3389 | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select CreationTime, RemoteAddress -First 1
```

**Output**

> ```
> CreationTime         RemoteAddress
> ------------         -------------
> 5/24/2021 7:40:33 AM 10.99.99.11
> ```

Furthermore, if you are running Windows versions that do not support the **Get-NetTCPConnection** cmdlet you could use the [IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections?view=net-5.0) and some parsing methods to get the IP address of the Remote Desktop Protocol connection(s) established.

### PowerShell Examples

**Note:** You will likely need to parse the LocalEndPoint by splitting on the semicolon to get the port. It'll be a trivial matter to figure out the exact logic you need here.

```
@([System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpConnections())
```

or

```
@([System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpConnections()) | % { $_.LocalEndPoint -Split(":") }
```

Comment: @S_T There you go, posted as an answer. You are welcome!

Comment: Also, if you want to share the full logic you used to work it out on Server 2008 R2, I can put that into my answer as well in case someone else comes across and needs it, you've already gotten the logic to parse, etc. for them. Might save someone else a headache or two.